# How to copy files from a custom encrypted azure blob container to Azure encrypted container

Tags: azure, parallel-processing, azure-blob-storage

We have a very large blob container containing blob blocks which we Encrypted using our own encryption.

We now wish to move all these blobs to a new storage container which will use Azure's encryption at rest

The only way I can think of is to write a worker role that  downloads to a stream decrypts it and uploads it. One at a time ...

That will probably take a while. Are they any other faster ways one can think of.Is there a way to parallelize this

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking. Why can't you just directly copy the blobs? The API (and SDKs) already support this 100%. What's the issue? Why would you need to decrypt? Your encryption is completely different from encryption-at-rest. Of course, if you want to get rid of your own encryption, then yes, you'd need to download / stream the blob somewhere, decrypt, and upload. But how you do that is fairly broad: worker role, vm, Azure function, Web job, etc...

Comment: Yes I want to get rid of my encryption. All i really want is a fast parallel way to do this

Comment: Lots of ways to do this: via code/sdk, queues/functions/etc, 1st/3rd-party tools, etc. The Azure team published AzCopy as a 1st-party tool, but have a look around to see what else is available. Unfortunately no right answer for you on this...

Answer (score 0):

As David Makogon mentioned that there are lots of ways to copy blobs.

> Is there a way to parallelize this.

Based on my experience, we could use [WebJob queue trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to) to do that.

We could [list the container blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#list-the-blobs-in-a-container) names and [write the blob url to storage queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues#insert-a-message-into-a-queue) or [service bus queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues#3-send-messages-to-the-queue).

In the webjob with your owner logic that download the blobs rid of your encryption and upload to another container.

Then we could [scale out the App service plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview#scale-an-app-service-plan) or use multiple webjobs to do that.